# r make filled contour with

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, contour

I am trying to make filled contour maps with data table of x,y and z values.

```
library(ggplot2)
x = 1:100
y = 1:100
z = 1:100

table = data.frame(x,y,z)

ggplot() + geom_point()

  geom_polygon(data = table,
               aes(x = x, y = y, z=z,
                   fill = ..fill.., group = ..piece..), 
               stat = "density2d", alpha = .5)
```

How should make it fill contour not with level, but with value z?

I want something like:

[image]

Comment: What does your code currently produce, if anything? And what is the intended result?

Comment: Look at the docs for `geom_contour`

Answer (score 1):

you might want something like this, though it requires different data:

```
x = rep(1:100,100)
y = rep(1:100,each = 100)
z = x + y

table = data.frame(x,y,z,f = z%/%10+1)

p <- ggplot(table, aes(x = x,y = y, z = z))

p + geom_tile(aes(fill = f))
```

[image]